# IOS Tab Bar with container

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uicontainerview, unwind-segue

I have a MAIN VC with buttons, then call Item 1 and Item 2 of Tab Bar Controller.
In Item 1 I have a container; inside a container a TABLE VIEW, then another Tab Bar Controller. Image below.

[image]

**The question:** how I can show the first view of container(TABLE VIEW) again(when I click in Item 1 of first Tab Bar Controller)? Because if I navigate inside a table and in second tab bar, and click again in the item 1 of the first tab bar, it will continues in the last view.

---

#### Solved

Solution: http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers

Comment: may be pop to root view controller will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` function...?

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController  *)self.window.rootViewController;
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```